# Tamanho dos painéis com facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Estou fazendo alguns gráficos em painel no `ggplot2`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ trans)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho a minha janela gráfica separada em 10 painéis distintos, pois `trans` é uma variável categórica com 10 níveis. Entretanto, se eu utilizar outra variável para os painéis, o resultado que obtenho é este:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ as.factor(year))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, meu gráfico tem dois painéis apenas, pois `year` tem apenas dois níveis.

Ocorre que o tamanho dos painéis depende do tamanho da janela gráfica e da quantidade de níveis da variável que eu usar em `facet_wrap`. Quanto mais níveis esta variável tiver, menor será a dimensão dos painéis internos.

O que eu devo fazer para que, ao criar dois gráficos de painéis com um número distinto de painéis, eles tenham todos o mesmo tamanho? Ou seja, como deixar os dois painéis do gráfico com `facet_wrap(~ as.factor(year))` com o mesmo tamanho dos painéis do gráfico com `facet_wrap(~ trans)`?

Note que esta mudança deve ser proporcional, isto é, o tamanho da fonte dos eixos deve permanecer constante de um gráfico para outro.

Comment: Bom, uma maneira é `facet_wrap(~ factor(year, levels = 1999:2008), drop = FALSE)` mas aposto que não é isto que quer.

Comment: De fato, isto resolve o problema da pergunta, mas não resolve meu problema real. As duas variáveis que tenho são fatores de fato e aí ficaria difícil de criar uma regra como esta. Fora que eu também gostaria que não aparecessem painéis vazios.

Comment: Creio que a função `ggplotGrob()` pode ser útil nesse caso.

Comment: Essa mudança teria que ser só na hora de salvar o gráfico com img, certo?

Comment: Sim. É para um relatório que estou escrevendo utilizando RMarkdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nesse caso o problema seria os painéis em branco

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

grafico_1 = ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ trans)

grafico_2 = ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ as.factor(year))

g1 = ggplotGrob(grafico_1)
g1$widths

g2 = ggplotGrob(grafico_2)
g2$widths

g2$widths = g1$widths
g2$heights = g1$heights

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g1)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Grande truque, não conhecia este. Está-se sempre a aprender.

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado.